# Checking extension on file from a given path in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file that I want to exit if the extension of the file given does not match my desired extension.

An example command would be:

```
>> Mybatfile -logfile C:\some\path\to\log\example.syslog
```

I want this to echo an error and exit because the extension of the given file is not ".log"

Here is my code:

```
IF "%~1"=="-install_log" (
 IF NOT EXIST "%~2" (
    echo "**********************"
    echo "ERROR: Log file %~2 does not exist. Exiting"
    goto exit
 ) ELSE IF /I NOT "%~x2%" == ".log" (
    echo "**********************"
    echo "ERROR: Log file is not an install log. Exiting"
    goto exit
 ) ELSE (
    ::
    :: Convert to unix format
    ::
    set LOGTEMP=%~2
    set INSTALL_LOG=!LOGTEMP:\=/!
 )
 SHIFT
) ELSE (
  ...
)
```

I hope I have made my problem clear enough. Thanks for your help!!

Miranda

Comment: You have made your goal clear, but not so your problem.

Comment: `%~x2%` is `.log`, not `log`

Comment: I apologize. My problem is that I have been unsuccessful in pulling out the extension of the file to compare it. I changed my code to make the suggestions with ".log" and edited my original post to reflect those changes. The other issue (potentially) is that the depth of the file will not be standard. In some cases in may only be one directory deep and in others is may be six directories deep. I am not sure if this plays a role or not. Thanks!

Comment: The extension (`%~x2`) doesn't depend on folder-depth. You show a first parameter `-logfile`. but check for `-install_log`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Evidently, you have `delayedexpansion` mode set. It would be helpful to indicate *where* that was set (in the mainline or in your subroutine). You should use `rem` remarks, not `::-remarks` in a code-block as `::` has a habit of terminating the block. And please, don't use a label `exit` as `exit` is itself a command. `goto :eof` will go to physical end-of-file, terminating a subroutine. This is built-in to `cmd` - the `eof` label should not be coded. The colon is *required*

Comment: @Stephan yes my bad. -logfile is another command used earlier in the file. -install_log is what I want, I changed the original post again. Sorry for all of the confusion

Comment: @Magoo Thanks for the coding tips, I really appreciate it! I'm not really familiar with batch at all, sadly.